# Mysql need sudo to run in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I can't run mysql without sudo. I think this the problem seen in 16.04 only. So I am looking for a solution for this. Can someone help me figure out this?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty normal for applications like Xampp, MySQL, etc. Unless you install it in the home directory, it is usually installed in places like /opt/, which usually needs sudo access to run (unless you forceably disable that with the chmod command)

to run as user
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/changing-mysql-user.html